# How do I transfer keystrokes between computers?

Tags: python

So, I have a python script on my pi 0w that takes in input from a wii remote and types a specific key, I was wondering if there was any way to duplicate the keystroke to my computer, or some way to make it look like the keystroke came from a usb device, so I could send it via a virtualhere connection. I have tried to use gpio output to an ardino leonardo, but it couldn't detect any input.
I am somewhat new to all of this, so sorry if I am just being stupid.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to turn the Pi into a HID (human interface device) and use that to send to keystrokes.  Not something I have done but a Google shows plenty of examples via a search for Pi 0 HID keyboard

Comment: No problem - glad you got it going from the little info I could give :-). If you could, please post the config and code you used as lost of links are now out of date (esp with Buster) so others can find the answer.